# google.script.run.function() in a shared file

Tags: google-apps-script

I got a sidebar in spreadsheets refering to a html-file with a button, which should run a function in my script with google.run.function(), when clicked. When I try it on my account, it works perfectly fine. But when I share it, the function isn't running if she clicks the button. Why is that?

```
 ausgabe.append('<p><input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="google.script.run.function(' + i + ')"></p>');
```

Comment: Can you please share the all script?

Comment: Coincidentally  I had a similar problem not to long ago. At my office we use GSuite, so we all use our company e-mail to log on to sheets. The function worked fine for everybody but two colleagues. Turned out that they also had their private gmail synchronized in Chrome and somehow it logged on with their private gmail, which I of course didn't authorize to run scripts so  google.script.run.function did nothing. 
Making the colleagues log on with their work email again fixed the problem.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, we tried this and it definitly has to do something with that. We don't have the solution yet, but we on it. Thanks for the help